# How Hide tool bar & bookmarks bar in pop-up windows, Firefox 124 mac OS

Tags: mac, firefox, gmail

I Use Mac OS Firefox as my primary client for Gmail, and I always compose emails in a pop-out window. Ever since Firefox 124, these pop-out windows include the tool bar and bookmarks bar, eating up a bunch of space. I do want those bars displayed on my main firefox window, I don't want them displayed on the pop-up Gmail compose windows. Is there anyway to get Firefox revert back to this old behavior?

Comment: Have you asked Firefox developpers?

Comment: No, but that is a great idea. I will post this question in their forums too.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the Bookmarks toolbar :

- Click *Menu > More tools > Customize Toolbar…*
- Right-click "Bookmarks toolbar items" and select
  *Bookmarks Toolbar* and then "Never show"
- Alternatively, you could press Ctrl+Shift+B.

You may do the same for any other toolbar inside the *Customize Toolbar…*
window.

Source :
[Bookmarks Toolbar - Display your favorite websites at the top of the Firefox window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-toolbar-display-favorite-websites).

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! Using the "Never show" menu option or Ctrl+Shift+B hides the toolbars in ALL firefox windows. I only want to hide the toolbars in pop-up windows, where they are redundant and eat up screen space.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that selectively, but you could use Ctrl+Shift+B as a flip-flop when in windows that you want (or not) to have them.